# The build_absolute_uri function always generates url with the http protocol

Tags: python, django, url, request

The build_absolute_uri function of the request object generates a url with the http protocol, although the url with the https protocol is obviously. Is it possible to somehow force the generation of a security protocol?

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem? @yozhik

Answer (score 0):

That sounds strange. The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) say, that the method `HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri()` always uses the protocol of the current request:

> Mixing HTTP and HTTPS on the same site is discouraged, therefore `build_absolute_uri()` will always generate an absolute URI with the same scheme the current request has [...]

Are you sure that you are using `https` in the current request?

Comment: Idea is url-shortener, and when i get the short url,for example https://urlcutt.herokuapp.com/LI28 with https , i try to go to this url, and in redirect view i call build_absolute_uri, then i see in traceback, that result of this functions -  http://urlcutt.herokuapp.com/LI28 with http

Comment: `class RedirectToOriginalView(RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        absolute_url = self.request.build_absolute_uri()
        url = Url.objects.filter(shortcut=absolute_url).first()
        return url.original`